# The authorized_keys permission denied only if I create the file when I mount the disk from other OS

Tags: ssh, authorized-keys

**Env:**

VM A : the machine I want to access with out password

VM B : I want to access VM A without password from the machine

**Problem Description:**

As I want to access VM A from VM B without password, I want first inject VM B's public key into VM A, but I still need password if I use ssh-copy, so I try to inject the file by mount.

**The steps:**

1. Start VM A from LiveCD
2. Mount VM A's root disk(contains the OS)
3. Create an authorized_keys file under ${mount_point}/root/.ssh/
4. Cat the VM B's public key into the authorized_keys file
5. Stop the VM A and remove the LiveCD then start the VM A again
6. Access the VM A from VM B by command

   *ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@9.112.224.130*

**Results:**

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

But after I did following commands, it works (file mode are all 600 and not difference with diff command)

```
mv authorized_keys authorized_keys_bak
cp authorized_keys_bak authorized_keys
```

so I try to inject it again, but for this time, I create an empty authorized_keys file before start from LiveCD, and skip the step 3, other step are all the same, for this time the VM B can access VM A without password

**Questions:**

1. The property for authorized_keys and authorized_keys_bak are all the same, why one works, one not works?
2. I authorized_keys can works only when I create the file not mount from LiveCD?

Answer (score 0):

ssh-copy-id will ask you password one time to inject the keys into remote system.

Logs which you have shown is from ssh client. We would need ssh server logs as well to check why ssh server is not able to verify user credentials.

From client logs, we can say, it has tried for publickey based (without password) authentication but it failed (means rejected by server). So remaining method is "keyboard-interactive" (which is supported by server) but client doesn't support it so no authentication method to try so it failed.

Can you also check following things for working & non-working scenerio

check user's publickey on client and server which is used for authentication
 on client -> /users//.ssh/id_rsa.pub
on server -> /etc/ssh/authorized_keys (check entry for your username)

Comment: The public key in client is the same with the key in server. and there also have no problem with the hostname, as when I execute the following command in server.  the client will can access the server without password



mv authorized_keys authorized_keys_bak


cp authorized_keys_bak authorized_keys

Comment: I guess problem is with mount as that location may not be accessible in process running sshd.

Comment: when I run ssh from the server, the client as been start normally, not from LiveCD,  so you mean there should be some problem with creating file during mount?

Comment: Yes, it could be the reason.

Comment: but there is no difference between these two file, one OK, one not OK, incomprehensible, any idea to find the root cause?

Comment: You may try running ssh server in debug mode. It will store logs in file. We can analyze that file which may give some hints..